# Resampling does not work as expected (see plot)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I was trying to understand what exactly `scipy.signal.resample` is to do. Here is a simple code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import resample
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t=np.linspace(1,4,10)
x=t
x_resampled=resample(x,10000)

plt.plot(x)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x_resampled)
```

the input is

[image]

and the output of code is

[image]

however, I expected

[image]

Can you please tell me how can I settle `scipy.signal.resample` to obtain such a result?

Comment: As this seems to be using fourier analysis, a straight line is not exactly the best way to test this function. Maybe a sine wave would do better (disclaimer: i've never used this function)

Comment: You may want to have a look [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp1d)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [documentation for resample](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.resample.html?highlight=resample#scipy.signal.resample) (emphasis mine):

> Because a Fourier method is used, the signal is **assumed** to be periodic.

On the *non-periodic* data you're using the above assumption doesn't hold. So a valid result should not be expected.